# Git actions, ignoring specific folders on .yml file

Tags: github, sftp, github-actions

im new using git actions.
So im using actions from git to automate deployment from my repository to my sftp server, everything works fine, but when the action is on execution takes to much time, around 20 minutes, on my repo exist files like system, application, and dist so, that kind of files i don't want to re-upload.
Doing a little research I found out that they can be ignored certains paths.

I found out that they can be ignored with "paths-ignore" but for some reason it's not working, this is my file.

[image]

I want to ignore all the content inside application/cache, application/config, application/core .. etc.Or all the folder "application/cache", "application/config".. etc

What am I doing wrong? It's possible to do that?

Comment: Small side note: These are not *Git* actions, they're *GitHub* actions. (Other hosting servers have very similar stuff, but they use different control files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have a suggestion:

> Don't put all these files inside your repository, `git` is for versioning code and not for storage.

`paths-ignore` is a config for `on:` event, which means when that `on` you have changes in your repository, except changes in `paths-ignore`, start the workflow.

There is no way to reduce too much time in your workflow because every `job` creates a new machine that gets all your git repository and starts some workflow. But you can read more about the SFTP-Deploy-Action and use the parameter `local-path` to upload just what you want, maybe your workflow drop to 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is, if i use local-path, i can only use one path, for example ./application/* but im i want to upload too ./static/js.

Comment: Try to restructure your repository first, probably you going to improve some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I put this answer as correct because it helps me to restructure my repository, not including core and system files, as you suggest "Don't put all these files inside your repository, git is for versioning code and not for storage.", it helps me, my workflow execution was reduced to 5 minutes.